# Some labels disappear when exported from QGIS to DXF

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, scale, dxf

I'm using QGIS 3.14.
I have two layers with labels in QGIS, set up to map units. In "rendering" section of label properties I have set up to show all labels for these layers.

I want to export these two layers to DXF, and I succeed partially - some labels are exported, and some not, irrelevant of the layers.

I use following export parameters:
Symbol layer symbology, scale 1:1000, encoding CP1252; Export labels as MTEXT elements; Export features intersecting the current map extent. Everything else is turned off.

It is worth mentioning that ALL block elements for points are exported, but only some MTEXT elements.

Any ideas?

[image: QGIS screen]

[image: CAD screen]

Comment: Have you made sure all labels are displayed, regardless of conflicts?

Comment: Yes, in both layers. That's why all labels are visible in QGIS, some were missing before i turned it on.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered something similar, but in my case all the labels couldn't export into DXF format. In my case, I simply changed my Encoding from ISO-8859-1 to CP936.
Note: The language of the labels is Greek, so I'm not sure if the Encoding is right, but I suppose that's where the problem is.

[image]